# How do I prevent Google Spreadsheet from opening in the List view mode on a mobile browser?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sites

It seems that no matter what I do my google spreadsheet inserted in Google site page opens in List view on a mobile browser (but not on the the desktop).

While it is a great feature in certain scenarios, sometimes it is just 'too much' as I do not need users to be able to sort or filter. How do I prevent the site from opening the spreadsheet in that List view mode?